# SwiftUI refresh list on alert accept

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm having an issue with SwiftUI implementation of refreshing list items within a SwiftUI list once one has been deleted.

The list represents a Users' friend requests, and each row is a unique instance of a view `FriendRequestRow()`

Here's an image showing what each row on the friend request list looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPPDI.jpg

My issue is that when the red X button is clicked and users are taken to an alert (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAoqH.jpg) and select 'Remove', it successfully removes the value from the application database, but the deleted row persists in the list until the view is re-rendered.

Below is the code for the view holding the list, with some non-essential lines removed.

```
struct FriendsListView: View {

@State var Friend_Request_Array : [Friend] = []
@State var Current_Friend_Array : [Friend] = []

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack{
            Text("Friend Requests")
            .font(.headline)
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)

            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray))
        .padding(.top, -8)

        // List of friend requests.
        List {
            ForEach(Friend_Request_Array) { Friend in
                FriendRequestRow(Friend: Friend, Friend_Display_Name: "")
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 150)

    }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Your Friends"), displayMode: .inline)
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {

    }) {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
    })
        .onAppear{
            self.Friend_Request_Array = []
            self.Current_Friend_Array = []
            self.Load_Friends()
    }
}

func Load_Friends() {
    // Load lists full of friends.

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    // Populates friend request array with pending friend requests.

    // Populates current friends array with all of the current users' friends.
}
```

}

Then, here's the view for each individual list row:

```
struct FriendRequestRow: View {

@State var Friend: Friend
@State var Friend_Display_Name: String

@State private var showingDeleteRequestAlert = false

var body: some View {
    HStack{
        Image("example-avatar")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .clipShape(Circle())

        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Text(Friend_Display_Name)
                .font(.headline)
        }.padding()

        Spacer()

        Button(action: {
            // Accept request.

        }) {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen))
        }


        Button(action: {
            // Deny and remove friend request. Should pop up an 'are you sure' alert.
            self.showingDeleteRequestAlert = true
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemRed))
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingDeleteRequestAlert) {
        Alert(title: Text("Are you sure?"),
              message: Text("If you delete this request it will have to be resent."), primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Remove")) {
                // Removal of request from the database

                // Re-render list
                // **THIS IS WHERE MY ISSUE IS, HOW DO I RERENDER LIST?**


            }, secondaryButton: .cancel())
        }


    }.onAppear{
        // Get Each users display name.
    }
}
```

As seen, I populate the list using the onAppear attribute when the view is loaded from a navigation link. However, this means that when users click to 'remove' each friend request, it doesn't get reflected in the list until the view is re-rendered (click back and then click the navigation link again). Help!

Comment: I'd recommend implementing a view model class instead of using `@State`. This will make your code cleaner and easier to reason about. In `onAppear()`, you would then call `fetchData()` on your view model, which in turn would register a snapshot listener on the query / collection you're interested in. In you view, subscribe to an `@Published` property on the view model. This way, your UI will update as soon as you receive an update. Check out https://peterfriese.dev/replicating-reminder-swiftui-firebase-part2/ for details.

Comment: @PeterFriese Thank you, much appreciated. I'll check out that article.